# Methods that inherit data types from a method before them?

Tags: java, methods, return, inherited

I would like to know how I can get the return value of a method and use it in another directly following it. For instance let's say I did this:

```
public Integer multiply(Integer n1, Integer n2){
    return n1 * n2;
}

//I know this is wrong but I don't know what params to put
public Integer add(Integer n1, Integer n2){
    return n1 + n2;
}

multiply(2, 2).add(???????);
```

In this I want to end up using the 4 from the multiply method as a value, then use the add method to add whatever value I give it to the result of the multiply which is four.

Note: I understand I could do:

```
add(multiply(2, 2), 3);
```

but I want to know how to use this format.

What I want to accomplish is:

```
Integer i = multiply(2, 2).add(5);
System.out.print(i);
```

to where when I run this the output will be 9 because 2 * 2 = 4 + 5 = 9. Please explain this to me :)

Comment: This is known as [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). You'll have to create a mutable integer class and add those methods, as @A4L has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Return a reference to the class holding the final value and doing operations on it using operands passed as arguments (see [Method cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) and [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)), something like that:

```
public class ALU {

    Integer value = 0;

    ALU mutiply(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        value = i1.intValue() * i2.intValue();
        return this;
    }

    ALU mutiply(Integer i) {
        value *= i.intValue();
        return this;
    }

    ALU add(Integer i) {
        value += i.intValue();
        return this;
    }

    ALU add(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        value = i1.intValue() + i2.intValue();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new ALU().mutiply(2, 2).add(5));
    }
}
```

The output is `9`

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer i = multiply(2, 2).add(5);
System.out.print(i);
```

here when you do

```
 multiply(2, 2)
```

it returns an `integer` and using that return type `Integer`, you are trying to call `add() method.

but `add() method` is not available inside `Integer` class with whatever the signature and intended you are trying to do.

so it complains like `add()` is not available inside `Integer` class.

so to achieve it make `multiple(2,2)` to return your own class and have a result in it.

and then call that `add()` method using that object easily in the way you want.

The way how you could achive the same is like below

```
package com.kb;

public class MultipleMethodCalls {

    int result;
    static MultipleMethodCalls m = new MultipleMethodCalls();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(m.multiply(2, 2).add(3));
    }

    public MultipleMethodCalls multiply(Integer n1, Integer n2){


       m.result= n1 * n2;
       return m;

    }

    //I know this is wrong but I don't know what params to put
    public Integer add(Integer n1){
        return this.result + n1;
    }


}
```